# Check multiple conditions OR PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there any more elegant way to write an IF with multiple OR conditions? Currently, my code is like below, but it doesn't look interesting like that.

```
if ( has_block( 'cgb/block-imoney-blocks' ) || has_block( 'cgb/block-idh-affiliates' ) || has_block( 'cgb/block-idh-best-summary') || has_block('cgb/block-idh-highlights')) {
    echo 'Value Found';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a lot of blocks it's more readable to iterate through an array like this:

```php
<?php
$blocks = ['cgb/block-imoney-blocks', 'cgb/block-idh-affiliates', 'cgb/block-idh-best-summary', 'cgb/block-idh-highlights'];

foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    if (has_block($block)) {
        echo 'Value Found';
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` is added to prevent multiple times execution of the if-statement but not strictly nessecary.

Comment: But might echo multiple times

Comment: Need `break` to prevent multiple run

Comment: I've updatet my answer. Thx! Feel free to vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

you could put the conditions in a function and pass the values in an array.

```
$blocks_array = array(
     'cgb/block-imoney-blocks',
     'cgb/block-idh-affiliates',
     'cgb/block-idh-best-summary',
     'cgb/block-idh-highlights'
);

if(contains_block($block_array)){
    echo 'Value Found';
}

function contains_block($block_array){
    foreach ($block_array => $block){
        if (has_block($block)){
            return true;
         }
    }
    return false:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With better formatting?

```
if ( has_block( 'cgb/block-imoney-blocks' ) 
  || has_block( 'cgb/block-idh-affiliates' ) 
  || has_block( 'cgb/block-idh-best-summary') 
  || has_block( 'cgb/block-idh-highlights')
  ) {
    echo 'Value Found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imo, make a `has()` function or similar which you can reuse, it then doesnt matter how long the lines are you have abstracted it. It would be equivalent to `some` (i.e some values in the array should be true).

```
function has($blocks) {
    return array_reduce($blocks, fn($acc, $cur) => $acc || has_block($cur), false);
}

if (has([
  'cgb/block-imoney-blocks', 
  'cgb/block-idh-affiliates', 
  'cgb/block-idh-affiliates'
])) echo 'Value Found';
```